# How would I make this small jQuery slider slide right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to get a slider to slide right, in addition to left. Two buttons named "Next" and "Previous" control the sliding.

Currently the slider slides left no problem. The variable `direction` holds whether the clicked button is "previous" (slide right) or "next" (slide left). I'm having trouble implementing the logic to make it so when `direction == 'previous'` the slider slides right. I would think it'd be simply negating some numbers but not so!

Here is the code prepared in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LWJQm/

For demo purposes this code is dumb-downed and only slides the same DIV over and over.

JavaScript here:

```
var $slider= $('#slider'),
    sliderHtml = $slider.html(),
    $next = $('#next'),
    $previous = $('#previous'),
    sliderWidth= parseInt($slider.css('width')),
    locked = false;

$('.button').on('click', function() {
    if (locked) {
        return false;   
    }

    locked = true;

    var direction = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(direction);

    var $transfer = $('<div></div>').css({'width': (2 * sliderWidth) + 'px'});
    var $current = $('<div></div>').css({'width': sliderWidth+ 'px', 'left': '0', 'float': 'left'}).html($slider.html());
    var $next = $('<div></div>').css({'width': sliderWidth+ 'px', 'left': sliderWidth + 'px', 'float': 'left'}).html(sliderHtml);

    $transfer.append($current).append($next);
    $slider.html('').append($transfer);

    $transfer.animate({'margin-left': '-' + sliderWidth+ 'px'}, 300, function() {
        locked = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i`m not sure i understand the problem. i moddified your fiddle with a simple if else statement. is this what your are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/flyingsausage/NvxKj/

Comment: I swear I tried that about a million times (it's the first thing I did), and it wasn't working. Time to hit my head against it some more.